# GetEnvironmentVariable() : Is this function firstly check nSize with variable value?

Tags: c++, environment-variables

```
DWORD WINAPI GetEnvironmentVariable(
_In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpName,
_Out_opt_ LPTSTR  lpBuffer,
_In_      DWORD   nSize
);
```

Is getEnvironmentVariable function first check for nSize and then write to lpBuffer OR it just blindly writes and results in Buffer-overflow problem ?

[Microsoft-MSDN function details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The function has to trust you pass the correct size to it, there's no bounds-checking except the `nSize` argument (and it really can't be).

If the value of `nSize` is larger than the actual buffer then the function might write out of bounds and lead to a buffer overflow.

Comment: No, the function will not cause overflow, at least that's what the documentation says.

Comment: @RSahu And *how* would the function know the size of the buffer? Sure it can use some knowledge of the internals of heap-allocated memory, but can it really? What if the buffer is allocated on the stack as a local variable? The only way it can check the size of `lpBuffer` is through the `nSize` argument, and if `nSize` is wrong the function will not know it.

Comment: The function assumes `lpBuffer` is capable of holding `nSize` characters. If the callee doesn't guarantee that, then the function could cause overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The function will never write in `lbBuffer` to cause overflow **if `lpBuffer` is capable of holding `nSize` characters**.

From [the documentation of GetEnvironmentVariable function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If *lpBuffer* is not large enough to hold the data, the return value is the buffer size, in characters, required to hold the string and its terminating null character and the contents of *lpBuffer* are undefined.